# I want to know which specific area of my Map (ImageView) was clicked

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

I am building an indoor map using an image, now I wanna know which specific area of my image was clicked so I can identify which room/corridor was selected.

I am using a "deep zoom" scalable imageview 
https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view
So with the panning and pinching zoom I am not sure if the x,y axis of the images would remain the same or not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try with `imageView.getLocationOnScreen(positionXY);`

Answer (score 0):

I think viewToSourceCoord method is what you searching for.

See Extensions -> Utility methods section from documentation 
https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/wiki/10.-Extension

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Staranchuk for pointing it out , I feel so stupid not going through all of the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read its own Github's Documentation? Link: https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/wiki/09.-Events ("*Using public methods on the class, you can convert the view coordinates of the event into coordinates of the source image*")

Comment: I am gonna try them today, my guess is you want me to access the method for motionevent like "motionevent.getX()". Thanks for the answer Mr.Emandt.

Comment: i'm sorry I couldn't get back earlier it was holiday season, well now that i'm back at work , I am facing the problem that my map is color coded and a certain building on that map would have multiple touch points as everyone won't touch the same point , how do I get a range x,y cordinates or a defined boundary cordinates to get know which building was touched ?